# How does todomvc Backbone's change to class 'editing' make todo editable?

Tags: javascript, css, class, backbone.js, todomvc

I'm going through [Backbone](http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/) tutorial and looking through the [source](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/backbone) code I don't understand the the doubleclicking event (todo-view.js), which leads to the edit method, which leads to the element getting the class 'editing' make the element (input) editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually a CSS trick. The input element is hidden by default:

```
.todo-list li .edit {
    display: none;
}
```

Then on dblclick the parent `li` element receives the `editing` class, and that makes the input visible with another rule:

```
.todo-list li.editing .edit {
    display: block;
}
```